# Cannot open backup device '/var/opt/mssql/backup/MyDB.bak'. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.)

Tags: sql-server, docker

I found a lot of cases, where people try to open a file from outside the docker container. But mine is clearly inside.

The whole message I am getting is:

```
$ /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P "mypw" -Q 
"RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = '/var/opt/mssql/backup/MyDB.bak'"
Msg 3201, Level 16, State 2, Server 1c7bf85afdaf, Line 1
Cannot open backup device '/var/opt/mssql/backup/MyDB.bak'. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.).
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server 1c7bf85afdaf, Line 1
RESTORE FILELIST is terminating abnormally.
```

Same happens when I try to actually restore the database. Any idea what is going wrong?

I have the feeling it might be some permission things where need to change permissions for the file

```
$ ls -la var/opt/mssql/backup/MyDB.bak
-rw-r----- 1 501 dialout 3395584 Jan 16 02:12 var/opt/mssql/backup/MyDB.bak
```

Comment: I have a similar issue, but for me the target is the issue:
```
mssql@,,,:/$ sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'myPW' -Q 'RESTORE DATABASE [v_1] FROM DISK = "/var/opt/mssql/backup/myBak.bak" WITH MOVE "v_1" TO "
/var/opt/mssql/data/v_1.mdf", MOVE "v_1_log" TO "/var/opt/mssql/data/v_1_log.ldf"'
...
The operating system returned the error '5(Access is denied.)' while attempting 'RestoreContainer::ValidateTargetForCreation' on '/var/opt/mssql/data/v_1.mdf'.
...
File 'v_1' cannot be restored to '/var/opt/mssql/data/v_1.mdf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
...
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The solution was to change the permission of the file.
I needed to do:

```
docker exec -it -u root MicrosoftSQLServer "bash"
```

Then change the user (`whoami` returns `mssql` when I run the docker container not as root)

```
chown mssql /var/opt/mssql/backup/TestDB.bak
```

And then it works.